# Bash - Brace expansion on result of command substitution?

Tags: bash

I want to prepend a string to all the files in a directory. What I want to do is something like:

```
echo string{$(ls some_dir)}
```

This won't work because ls separates words with spaces, and brace expansion requires commas. So I thought I'd use `tr` to replace the spaces with commas, like:

```
echo string{$(ls some_dir) | tr ' ' ','}
```

But that doesn't work either because the pipe takes precedence.

What's the correct way to do this? I know I could probably use a sane language like Python, but it's frustrating that Bash can't even do something as simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to interpolate the contents of a directory (which is what $(ls some_dir) would give you) then you can do

```
printf 'string%s ' some_dir/*
```

IRL, you probably want it to end with a newline.

```
{ printf 'string%s ' some_dir/*; echo; }
```

You can generalize this to the output of any glob or brace expansion:

```
printf 'foo%d\n' {11..22}
```

#### Edit

Based on your comment, you want to eliminate the "some_dir/" part, you can't merely do that with `printf`. You can either `cd` to the directory so the globs expand as desired, or use parameter expansion to clean up the leading directory name:

```
( cd some_dir && printf 'string%s ' *; echo )
```

or

```
{ cd some_dir && printf 'string%s ' * && cd - >/dev/null; echo; }
```

or

```
names=( some_dir/* ) names=( "${names[@]#some_dir/}" )
{ printf 'string%s ' "${names[@]}"; echo; }
```

Comment: No, that's not what I need. `ls some_dir` shows `a b c`, while `echo some_dir/*` shows `some_dir/a some_dir/b some_dir/c`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, which will deal gracefully with whitespace in filenames:

```
files=("$dir"/*); files=("${files[@]/#"$dir"\//"$prefix"}")
```

That will store the prefixed strings in the array `$files`; you could iterate over them using an array expansion:

```
for file in "${files[@]}"; do 
  # Something with file
done
```

or print them out using `printf`:

```
printf "%s\n" "${files[@]}"
```

The advantage of using the array expansion is that it does not involve word-splitting, so even if the elements have whitespace in them, the array expansion will contain each element as a single word.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, bash can do it.

Let's go step by step.

**1. fix an issue in your second example**

This is your second example

```
echo string{$(ls some_dir) | tr ' ' ','}
```

You put pipe outside the command substitution, which is totally wrong.

I believe you want to pipe the stream from `ls` output to `tr` input, so it's obvious that the pipe is supposed to be put inside the command substitution, like this

```
echo string{$(ls some_dir | tr ' ' ',')}
```

**2. output of `ls` is separated by newline rather than whitespace**

so here we go

```
echo string{$(ls some_dir | tr '\n' ',')}
```

**3. brace expansion is performed prior to command substitution**

In the other word, after command substitution is expanded to `f1,f2,f3,d1,`, the brace expansion will not be performed any more.

So, no doubt, the command will print `string{f1,f2,f3,d1,}`.

The solution is letting bash evaluate it again.

```
eval echo string{$(ls some_dir | tr '\n' ',')}
```

OK, up to now, the result looks very good (try it yourself, you'll get it), it is very close to what you were looking for, except one tiny spot.

You may already noticed the comma at the end of the output I demonstrated above. The comma results in an unnecessary `string` appearing at the end of the final output.

So let's make it done.

**4. remove the ending comma**

```
eval echo string{$(echo -n "$(ls some_dir)" | tr '\n' ',')}
```

OK, this is it.

---

Oh... BTW., this is just an specific solution for your specific question. You may develop new variants of your question, and this specific solution may not fit your new question. If so, I suggest you run `man bash`, and read it from head to toe very very carefully, then you will become unstoppable.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't actually remember what was I using this for, but IIRC I probably ended up switching to Python, since Bash is such a brittle, complex mess. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Hi, you are welcome. Python is a good choice. It is a programming language, so theoretically it can do anything. I just want to make a defense for bash. It is really not complex. In fact, combining with various commands, it is very easy to handle issues about file, file name, directory, file system, etc. The final answer I offered, don’t you think it is pretty short and simple? However, please never mind what I say. All roads lead to Rome. :)

Comment: I humbly disagree. Bash is a complex and badly designed language, with obscure syntax, multiple special cases and exceptions to pretty much every rule. If you can't realize this, though, I'm afraid there's not much I can do to convince you otherwise.

Comment: haha, it’s right, we can’t convince each other, and we both are able to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ rename -nv '' PREFIX_ * | grep -Po "' -> \`\K.*(?='$)”
```

This creates a file renaming sequence without actually doing the rename, then parsed the output for just the target of the rename. E.g.,

```
$ ls -A --fu --si
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 larry wheel 0 2024-01-02 16:58:46.870589000 -0600 a
-rw-r--r-- 1 larry wheel 0 2024-01-02 16:58:46.870678000 -0600 b
-rw-r--r-- 1 larry wheel 0 2024-01-02 16:58:46.870737000 -0600 c
$ rename -nv '' PREFIX_ * | grep -Po "^\`[^']+' -> \`\K.*(?='$)"
PREFIX_a
PREFIX_b
PREFIX_c
```

This may not work with really weird file names, or some unicode characters in file names.

Comment: (Hopefully obvious, if what you were trying to do was actually rename files, the `rename` command may come in handy.)